# React Component receives the Redux states but can't dispatch actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, dispatch

The action I want to trigger works on its own, the axis request works and it retrieves data from an api. However when I try to run it from the component using connect and then accessing it as a prop, it is like the function doesn't run, and the redux state don't update accordingly.

This is how I use connect with my react component (getChannels is imported before from the action js file

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  channels: state.Channels.channels,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ getChannels })(ChannelList)
```

This is how I call the function inside the component

```
componentDidMount(){

    this.props.getChannels
   
  }
```

When I log the props to the console I get the initial redux states, and a function object.

[console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS0QJ.png)

I have tried different ways of dispatching the action but I am new to this so I can't identify why it doesn't work. Below is my action file

```
import axios from 'axios'

import { GET_CHANNELS } from "./types";


// GET CHANNELS

export const getChannels = () => (dispatch) => {

 
 axios
  .get('/TeamChat/RetrieveChannels')
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    dispatch({
      type: GET_CHANNELS,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

And bellow is my reducer

```
   import { GET_CHANNELS } from '../actions/types.js';


const initialState = {
  channels: ['channel 1'],
}


export default function (state = initialState,action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case GET_CHANNELS:
      return {
        ...state,
        channels: action.payload
  };
    default:
      return state;

  }
}
```

Thank you so much for helping me... I have been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmL8iaLMnQ0&list=PLillGF-RfqbbRA-CIUxlxkUpbq0IFkX60&index=4&ab_channel=TraversyMedia, and I can't identify where I am making a mistake.

Comment: `This is how I call the function inside the component` `this.props.getChannels`. You're not actually calling it, you need parentheses: `this.props.getChannels()`

Comment: thank you @NicholasTower !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the method,
so do
`this.props.getChannels()`
instead of
`this.props.getChannels`

But generally, you should be using the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks in 2022. `connect`/`mapStateToProps` are a legacy api that is only around to provide support for legacy class components. If you are following a tutorial sthat shows you `connect`, it probably also shows you other outdated concepts: modern Redux does not use `switch..case` reducers, ACTION_TYPEs, hand-written action creators, immutable reducer logic or `createStore` and `applyMiddleware`. As a consequence, modern Redux is less prone to bugs, easier to read and only 1/4 of the code. If your tutorial is still showing these outdated practices, please follow [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) instead.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for replying so quick you saved me so much trouble !!! Okay I will do with the official tutorial, cause I had been using the switch etc. Thank you !